# Is $eq inductive in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

Before restructuring my database, I would like to ask : does the MongoDB operator $eq compare JSONs in depth ?

For example, would it regard as equal the 2 following documents in MongoDB ?

```
{"a": {"b": {"c": 0}}
{"a": {"b": {"c": 1}}
```

I agree that I can make this test by myself but, as there may be a maximum depth in the comparison, I would have to ask the question in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#read-operations-embedded-documents) Equality matches on the whole embedded document require an exact match of the specified  document, **including the field order.**
Therefore, as much as I have not tested, mongo will "compare JSONs in depth" and thus the two documents **WILL NOT** be regareded as equal. Note that Mongo supports a max BSON depth of 100, and this should also be the theoretical depth of making queries

Comment: Thanks, I had been on this page but overlooked.